# JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at Python even I tried with strict = False to neglect characters like /n

Tags: python, json, spyder, data-analysis

Here is my code :

```
import json
path = 'usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
print(open(path).readline())
records = [json.loads(line,strict=False) for line in open(path)]
print(records[0])
```

I got an error message as `JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at`. I am using the `json` module to read the JSON file line by line using python.

I couldn't get the expected output. Can anyone help to solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you able to provide the JSON file (or a snippet of the file) which you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/kojoidrissa/pydata-book/blob/master/ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt  This is the link I used to get the JSON file from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there try this,

```
import json
path = 'usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
print(open(path).readline())
records = [json.dumps(line) for line in open(path)]
final_records = [json.loads(lines) for lines in records]
print(final_records[0])
```

Comment: It is working but  why you use lines instead of line in the final_records statement

Comment: Because that is another loop for json.loads @AasikMohamed